# pinescript, set long (or short) Condition from stop order

Tags: pine-script

i have a proble to "transalte" an order on a statment. For example if you buy at ema cross you write this :

```
   slowema=ema(close,26)
longCondition= crossover(fastema,slowema)

if longCondition
     strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
```

OK all work good. I need to create a "longCondition" statment starting to this:

`strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, stop=value)`

My problem is to create a `longCondition` statment to use it in other situation, i need something like :

```
longCondition = stop=value
```

Written this way is wrong, so how i can "translate" a "stop=value" situation in a `longCondition` statment? do you have any solution?

Comment: Please explain in English terms what you are trying to achieve, your intent is unclear.

Comment: thank you Machavity pine script support answer to me, and this is not possible to do.